# jQuery SLider with Double for range

Tags: jquery, html, web-applications

This is the first time I've worked with jQuery. I'm trying to create a slider for adjusting PH values which is in double (0.0 - 14.0). Is this possible? I have a code but its range is in integer, when I try to put a double in there, the slider get stuck in one place. Below is the code.

```
// Slider for PH Level
    $('#sliderLevel').slider({
            orientation: "vertical",
            range: "min",
            min: 0,
            max: 14,
            value: 0,
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
                    $( "#amountLevel" ).html( ui.value );
            }
    });
    $( "#amountLevel" ).html( $( "#sliderLevel" ).slider( "value" ) );
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, just use `step` property of a decimal amount:

```
// Slider for PH Level
    $('#sliderLevel').slider({
            orientation: "vertical",
            range: "min",
            min: 0,
            max: 14,
            value: 0,
            step: 0.05,
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
                    $( "#amountLevel" ).html( ui.value );
            }
    });
    $( "#amountLevel" ).html( $( "#sliderLevel" ).slider( "value" ) );
```